# double square bracket in 'case' in 'configure.ac' i[[3456]]86

Tags: bash, shell, autoconf

I am trying to understand the following code snippet.

```
host_cpu='i386'

case "$host_cpu" in
   i[[3456]]86)
       echo "host_cpu=i386"
   ;;
   x86_64)
       echo "host_cpu=x86_64"
   ;;
   *)
       echo "AC_MSG_ERROR([unsupported CPU type]) "
   ;;
esac
```

I added the variable `host_cpu='i386'` myself to test the code and it switched to the third case of `echo "AC_MSG_ERROR([unsupported CPU type]) "`.

If I change the double bracket in `i[[3456]]86)` to a single bracket as in `i[3456]86)`, it switches to the first option yielding `i386`. This seems correct to me.

I understand that `[` and `[[` are the test options. The test condition doesn't seem to apply here as the switch cases are expecting a character to be outputted. So I'm assuming for bash to pick it up as a test condition, it needs to be separated by a space as in `[ a < b ]` or `[[ a << b ]]`. Because there are no spaces in these case statement, it'll be treated as a regular expression. Is this correct?

So my question is why was the double square bracket was used here by the code writer? It didn't work when I tried to run the code, so what was their intention.

Note: The code was taken from a `configure.ac` in the GRUB source code.

Also the $host_cpu and host_cpu=i386 line seem unnecessary, can you explain why the writer would have done this:

```
AC_CANONICAL_HOST

case "$host_cpu" in
    i[[3456]]86) host_cpu=i386 ;;
    x86_64) host_cpu=x86_64 ;;
    *) AC_MSG_ERROR([unsupported CPU type]) ;;
esac

AC_SUBST(host_cpu)
AC_SUBST(host_vendor)
```

I'm thinking of using AC_SUBST($host_cpu). Why wouldn't you do it this way?

Comment: Looks like a bug.  I suggest you submit a pull request.  And no, it's not a regular expression; it's pattern matching, which works the same as file globs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If that's a from a `configure.ac` file, then it's not a pure shell script, but is an Autoconf script using [M4, where `[]` are quote characters.](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#M4-Quotation):

> To fully understand where proper quotation is important, you first
>   need to know what the special characters are in Autoconf: ‘`#`’
>   introduces a comment inside which no macro expansion is performed,
>   ‘`,`’ separates arguments, ‘`[`’ and ‘`]`’ are the quotes themselves,
>   ‘`(`’ and ‘`)`’ (which M4 tries to match by pairs), and finally ‘`$`’
>   inside a macro definition.
>
> Each time there can be a macro expansion, there is a quotation
>   expansion, i.e., one level of quotes is stripped:
>
> ```
>  int tab[10];
>  ⇒int tab10;
>  [int tab[10];]
>  ⇒int tab[10];
> ```

That `[[3456]]` should be expanded by autoconf to `[3456]`, which would be the correct output for use as a shell script.

Comment: Indeed - as one can verify by adding a minimal `AC_INIT([foo])` to the top of the snippet and then executing `autoconf snippet`

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've read about m4 and they used the quote characters ` and ' in those articles. So the must have changed the quotes in the configure.ac to treat [ and ] as quotes.

Comment: The link you provided use [ and ] as quotes. Does this depend on M4 version used?

Comment: @supmethods you can [change the quote characters in M4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Changequote), and it seems `[ ]` are set as quote characters in autoconf scripts. The default quote characters in M4 are `\`' `, as you have seen.

Comment: I updated the post and would like to know the main purpose of the case statement. AC_CANONICAL_HOST computes the host_cpu, host_vendor, and host_os. Doesn't it mean that you don't need assignment of the variables (as in host_cpu=i386 and host_cpu=x86_64), and that you can simply do an "if $host_cpu is false then AC_MSG_ERROR([unsupported CPU type])"? host_cpu should already be set from AC_CANONICAL_HOST,  so shell variable can be set straight away (AC_SUBST(host_cpu) without the assignment).

Comment: @supmethods since they're matching against i486, i586 and i686, and setting those cases to i386, obviously it's not sufficient.

Comment: ok, makes complete sense. Just wanted to check to ensure it's not my misunderstanding of the language. Thanks.